# Can I install Ubuntu 17.04 on a laptop Alienware 17 R3 without damage?

Tags: system-installation, alienware

I want to install Ubuntu 17.04 but I dont know if this could damage my laptop.

I have:

i7 6700HQ
NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 970M
16GB RAM
1TB HDD

Comment: you can because linux kernel supports every hardware with his generic drivers but I don't recommend you to do that, an alienware is a pc for gaming or hard render programs, in linux you will encounter so many gitches that may make you annoyed, if your purpose is to do simple stuff with that laptop ,learn linux and then give it a try.

Comment: Perfect. Thank You! this is for a school practice! and well in the past i only install ubuntu in VM! i will try in the pc onle for a few days! i apreciate the answer!

Comment: @JesusAlbino If Windows is already installed on the machine and you think you may want to keep using it, then you might want to install Ubuntu alongside windows in a dual-boot configuration, rather than replacing the Windows system altogether. These days, many games do support GNU/Linux operating systems like Ubuntu, but if you're using the system for gaming then you still might want to keep Windows, because some games still only run on Windows (or Windows and macOS), and because you won't know how well Ubuntu will perform for high-end games on your hardware until you try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Your machine has more than the minimum system requirements for installing Ubuntu 17.04.

## Minimum system requirements

Ubuntu Desktop Edition

```
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Internet access is helpful
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

And installing Ubuntu may damage your HDD contents if you do not know what to do in partitioning step during Ubuntu installation.

If you have a fresh system and do not have any data on your machine (HDD) simply boot up system with Ubuntu Disk or USB installer and follow clear steps to install it.

If you have another operating system like Microsoft Windows and want to dual boot your computer with Windows & Ubuntu you must do pre-installation steps.

This is a good tutorial for safely partitioning your system and making it dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu.
[The Ultimate Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux Dual Boot Guide](https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-guide-2200653)

But this is my way of doing that:

I suggest that in Windows you shrink a partition and obtain 100 GiB free space (write on paper exact size of it) steps 3, 4, 5  and in Ubuntu installation process in **Installation Type** select **Something Else** and go on to **Create Partitions Manually** step 13. other steps are straightforward.

Comment: make the partition step by step tutorial and I will give you +1